# How to increment X-Axis tick marks correctly so it is readable and evenly spaced?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

I'm using pandas & matplot to plot this data set all I'm using is the following:

```
data.plot(kind = 'scatter', x="Avg" , y="# Ratings")
plt.show()
```

The Y-axis comes out correct, but the X-axis draws a tick for every data point like this:
[image]

I was hoping to have something like the Y-axis with tick marks spread more evenly and readable.
I tried data.xticks it didn't work very well

Comment: You probably need to convert your x-values to numbers (or matplotlib dates).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [MaxNLocator](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/ticker_api.html#matplotlib.ticker.MaxNLocator):

```
from matplotlib.ticker import MaxNLocator

ax = data.plot(kind = 'scatter', x="Avg" , y="# Ratings")
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(MaxNLocator(20))
```